# check assignability without compiler error

Tags: typescript

I want to find a way to check if two variables can be assigned to each other.

But at the same time I don't want it to be a compile error, so the following does not fit my needs:

```
let x: { _type: 'a' }
let y: { _type: 'b' }
y = x // error
```

One of my ideas is to somehow combine them an get the `never` type.
If I can do that, I can test it with `typeAssert.isNever()` from `type-plus`:

```
let z: never
typeAssert.isNever(z)
```

I tried `{ _type: 'a' } & { _type: 'b' }` but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution: `Extract<{ _type: 'a' }, { _type: 'b' }>` would give me `never`